# error: magic.h: No such file or directory (MacOS X V 10.6.8)

Tags: c++, macos, linker, cmake

I am developing a project called "[Duplicate File Finder](https://github.com/devgeekco/duplicate_file_finder)" where I also want to extract the information about the type of the file i.e. png, zip, executable etc. I found out that libmagic (magic.h) can be used for finding filetype. But the problem I am facing for quite some time is that magic.h is not recognized when I compile the module. My project uses 'cmake' build system. I defined all the parameters in CMakeLists.txt and even it is not giving error when I am finding path and library for magic as it is installed in my system. *I can do 'man libmagic' and it works*. Following is my cmake file. Following is my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( duplicateFinder )

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) 
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(USE_OPENSSL TRUE)
find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem regex thread REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL)
FIND_PATH(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h)
find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARY sqlite3)
FIND_PATH(MAGIC_INCLUDE_DIR magic.h)
find_library(MAGIC_LIBRARY magic $ENV{MAGIC_LIB_PATH})

if(NOT MAGIC_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find magic.h")
endif()
if(NOT MAGIC_LIBRARY)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find the magic library")
endif()

if(NOT SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find sqlite3.h")
endif()
if(NOT SQLITE3_LIBRARY)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find the sqlite3 library")
endif()

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(duff_SOURCES src/run_duff.cpp src/sys_scan.cpp src/duff_utils.cpp)
    SET(duff_HEADERS src/run_duff.h src/sys_scan.h src/duff_utils.cpp)
    add_executable(bin/dup_finder ${duff_SOURCES} ${duff_HEADERS})
    add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
    add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )
    target_link_libraries(bin/dup_finder ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY} ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY} ${MAGIC_LIBRARY} )                                           
endif()
```

I did an intensive research on Internet but was not able to solve the problem. I hope the problem statement is understandable. Can anybody help me in this regards. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I read the project source and understood very little - Could you please explain what do you use for 'magic' implementation? is it from BOOST? have you found any library/service on the MacOS that provides the functionality? Can't understand this from the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
include_directories(${MAGIC_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

---

*Additional comments:* Since boost is `REQUIRED`, CMake will fail if it is not found, so it is a bit weird to wrap everything inside an `if(Boost_FOUND)`.
It's doubly confusing since you link the non-boost libraries inside this `if` as well…

Also, you should add `${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR}` to the `include_directories` as well, since on another machine, they may be in a place not already included.

Comment: Thanks a ton Simon! Now, it got compiled! :D

and regarding your comments, you are absolutely right. Even at one point I found that weird but out of excitement to get going with programming I was ignoring it. I will try to restructure it soon. Thanks for your valuable comments. If you find time, can you also please have a look into my project and give comments for improvement in matters of writing code and project in general.